# Repository remove method not working - Object not found

Tags: c#

```
  public class Hardware
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int  Nodes { get; set; }
    public int  Repeaters { get; set; }
    public int  Hubs { get; set; }

}

public abstract class Repositories<T> where T:class
{
    //where T:class fixes the issue with .SET


    //Repository class constructor once initialized will instantiate  datamodel
    //Manufacturing data model instantiate because it models table

    ManufacturingDataModel MDM;
    public Repositories( ManufacturingDataModel mdm)
    {
        MDM = mdm;
    }

    public List<T> GetHardware()
    {
        //Creating new list and adding data from db in it

        List<T> data = new List<T>();
        foreach(var i in MDM.Set<T>())
        {
            data.Add(i);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public void AddHardware(T item)
    {
        MDM.Set<T>().Add(item);
        MDM.SaveChanges();

    }


    public void RemoveHardware(T item)
    {
        MDM.Set<T>().Remove(item);
        MDM.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void UpdateHardware(T item)
    {
        MDM.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(item);
        MDM.SaveChanges();
    }



public class Test : Repositories<Hardware>
{
    public Test(ManufacturingDataModel mdm) : base(mdm)
    {
    }



 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManufacturingDataModel MDM = new ManufacturingDataModel();
        Test t = new Test(MDM);

        Hardware hardware = new Hardware();

        hardware.Nodes = 55;
        hardware.Repeaters = 46;
        hardware.Hubs = 82;



        t.AddHardware(hardware); // WORKS

        t.RemoveHardware(hardware); //DOES NOT WORK
```

[image]

I'm trying to make a working repository to add/remove items from my db table. The issue I'm facing is that the add method works perfectly but the remove does not. The issue with the remove method as shown in the picture is that the object does not exist.
I've tried different things such as change my remove method to DeleteObject and Attach but nothing seems to be working.
Any ideas?
ADO --> code first --> EF --> Repo class

Answer (score 0):

You have first to fetch the item you want to remove and the remove it:

```
public void RemoveHardware(T item)
{
    var dbItem = MDM.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == item.Id);
    if(dbItem!=null)
    {
        MDM.Set<T>().Remove(dbItem);
        MDM.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Update**

As it is stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove(v=vs.113).aspx), `DbSet.Remove`

> Marks the given entity as Deleted such that it will be deleted from
>   the database when SaveChanges is called. **Note that the entity must**
>   **exist in the context** in some other state before this method is called.

In your case the item is not in your context and this is the reason you see the following error:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager

If the item was in the context then as correctly Rainman has pointed out in his comment below, we woulnd't have to make the extra roundtrip to the database to fetch the item.

Comment: In your scenario, if we have "item.Id" info, we don't need to query the entity again. It hits the database twice.

Comment: As you can read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove(v=vs.113).aspx, The `Remove` *Marks the given entity as Deleted such that it will be deleted from the database when SaveChanges is called. **Note that the entity must exist in the context** in some other state before this method is called.* Usually when someone request the deletion of an item this is not in context. This is why I said so and this is why the OP see this error.

Comment: Yes you are right. We must attach the entity to exist in the context before trying to delete it. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **unique Id (mostly primary key)** for **Hardware** entity. 
It is something like that;

```
        Hardware hardware = new Hardware();

        hardware.Id = 1 //Set your unique Id here
        hardware.Nodes = 55; //Not necessary
        hardware.Repeaters = 46; //Not necessary
        hardware.Hubs = 82; //Not necessary
        RemoveHardware(hardware);

        // So edit your RemoveHardware method too like this
        public void RemoveHardware(T item)
        {
           MDM.Set<T>().Attach(item);
           MDM.Set<T>().Remove(item);
           MDM.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want make it work, once the object has been inserted retrieve it from the database and pass it in the RemoveHardware method.

As you are passing an object without the primary key, you are getting that error.